# Match fixed-width numbers with right-padded contiguous whitespace

Tags: python, regex, fixed-width

I am trying to validate a format within a larger regular expression and block of fixed-column text.  I would like to match a fixed-width pattern, but only if it has only digits on the left, and only whitespace (or none) on the right. The resulting expression will be used within python.

The following lines should match the 17 digit pattern (except the header):

```
MATCH
  *****************
A 20081122122332444 B
A 20081122122332    B
A 200811221223      B
A 2008112212        B
A 20081122          B
```

But the following should not match

```
NO MATCH
  *****************
A 20081122112233 1  B
A 2008112211223 1   B
A 200811221     C   B
A 20081122 .        B
```

This regex matches the valid data easy enough: `(?=\d+\s*)[\d\s]{17}`

This also seems to pick up the corrupting characters: `(?=\d+[\s]?[^\d])[\d\s]{17}`

A negative lookbehind will not work, due to the varying position, and I would rather not repeat the pattern to work all the possible variants for the string length.

It would seem there is an elegant way to do this within a regex - capture a contiguous block of digits, followed by a contiguous block of space, for a total of 17 characters.

Comment: Is there a boundary on the right after matching 0+ whitespace chars? For example is there a rule after 17 digits or whitespaces? Can there only be non digits or whitespaces following? What is the meaning of A and B in the example data? Is the column length 18?

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem with your pattern is that you're using `[\d\s]{17}`. This will match a string of 17 characters of *a mixture of digits and whitespaces*. While you want to make sure both the digits and the whitespaces (if any) are consecutive.

For restricting the length of the string, you may use a positive Lookahead to validate that the whole string is exactly 17 characters. Then you match any number of digits (length already restricted), optionally, followed by whitespace characters.

You may use the following pattern:

```
^(?=.{17}$)\d+\s*?$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/H7BOa4/1).

Comment: This would appear to depend on the pattern terminating at end-of-line. If I have other characters there (continuing patterns to match separately), it now matches on a partial of the line. Although this modification might work: https://regex101.com/r/RWVe14/2

Comment: @interplanetary Not really. In this pattern, the Lookahead is actually redundant and more than 17 digits/whitespaces would be matched anyway. If there's nothing to restrict what's before/after the 17 desired chars, I don't think there would be a regex-only solution (I could be wrong). **But**, if you know what comes before and after as you indicate in your link, you could use something like this instead: `A\s(?=.{17}\sB)(\d+\s*?)\sB` and you'll have your desired 17 chars in the first capturing group ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ges6Fi/1)). Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Since the OP wants to match a regular expression within larger regular expression, you should drop the `^` and `$` anchors. But a problem remains: `(?=.{17}$)\d+\s*?` will match no spaces in `'1234567890                           '` while `(?=.{17}$)\d+\s*` will match too many spaces in `'1234567890                        '`. (I tried to add extra spaces at the end of `1234567890`, but they are not appearing)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve objective by searching for digits , followed by space and counting number of characters in span

    `import re
    text="20081122 .      "

    if re.search('[\d]{1,}[\s]{0,}',s).span()[1]==17:
        print("yes")
    else print("no")`

Answer (score 0):

You say you are looking for 17-character width columns and so I will only match up to 17 characters, since it is not clear what can follow these 17 characters (might be extra spaces, which appears to be the case):

```
import re

text = """A 20081122122332444 B
A 20081122122332    B
A 200811221223      B
A 2008112212        B
A 20081122          B"""

l = [m.group(0)[0:17] for m in re.finditer(r'\d+\s*', text) if m.span(0)[1] - m.span(0)[0] >= 17]

print(l)
```

Prints:

```
['20081122122332444', '20081122122332   ', '200811221223     ', '2008112212       ', '20081122         ']
```

If you are using this as part of a larger regex, then perhaps we have to then assume that the 17-character column is followed by a space and we then have:

```
(?=\d[\d\s]{16})\d+\s*(?=\s)
```